# Memoize a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-usememo

There is a component that receives props.

The props has the shape of an array, for each element of this array, a function is going to return a different component to render.

```
function MainComponent ({ data }) => { // data is props, an array

  const specialFunction = (index) => {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return <Component0 />;
    case 1:
      return <Component1 />;
    case 2:
      return <Component2 />;
    default:
      return null;
    }
  };
  ...
  return (
     ...
     data.map((item, index) => {
        ... // do other stuff with item
        <div>{specialFunction(index)}</div> // the function that we talk about
   
     ...
  );
```

Is there a way to memoize the result of this if the props is not going to change? Or any way to write it better?

Comment: did you try the obvious - `useMemo(specialFunction, [index])`?

Comment: You can try with `useMemo` or `memo`.

Comment: For functions, you can also use useCallback.

Comment: In your example the function could just live outside of `MainComponent`.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of way to achieve this:

1. You could use a state to store the array

`const [components] = useState([<Component0 />, <Component1 />, <Component2 />])`

And then just use `components[index]` when trying to render.

2. You could try `useCallback` to memoize your function.

Answer (score -1):

[useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) with empty dependency array will be the best approach here.
useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. Since our dependeny array is `[]` it will be initialized only once and the returned memonized function is used in subsequent function calls.

```
const specialFunction = useCallback((index) => {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return <Component0 />;
    case 1:
      return <Component1 />;
    case 2:
      return <Component2 />;
    default:
      return null;
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: It will be executed n times per render call (where n is length of `data`). "it will be executed only once" is misleading

Answer (score -1):

Other pattern, I think in this case the most elegant is to use:

```
const components = {
   0: <Component0 />,
   1: <Component1 />,
   2: <Component2 />,
}

/*
or
const components = [<Component0 />, <Component1 />, <Component2 />]
*/

function MainComponent ({ data }) => {
  ...
  return (
     ...
     data.map((item, index) => 
        <div>{components[index] || null}</div>
     ...
  );
```